# Mixed logistic model with complete separation

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, separation

I want am trying to produce a mixed logistic model but certain explanatory variables suffer from complete separation. I am aware that I need to either use exact logistic regression or a firth correction. However, I cannot find any implementation of either for mixed models. Any ideas?