# GLMER Overdispersion and Error messages

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, eigenvalues, overdispersion

I have a data set which involves 30 binomial absence/presences totalled for a ratio out of 1, which is the total score of a test out of 30 marks.
The data requires fitting one of my predictor variables as a random effect,

```
glmer1 <- glmer(formula= cbind(NumberPresent, NumberAbsent) ~ Year + 
   Class + Gender + (1|School), data = Framework1, 
   family = "binomial"(link="logit"))
```

`summary(glmer1)`  gives

```
AIC  4112.8     
BIC 4135.9
logLik -2051.4
deviance 4102.8
df.resid 732
```

Obviously the data is still overdispersed after the inclusion of a random effect. My question is: Should i use a GLM with quasibinomial? Or stay with `glmer` with the random effect? Or is there a better way to do it?

Also: I get this error returned when i try to run the glmer.

```
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

Is this because of the nature of my variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot on this in the [relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fitting-models-with-overdispersion): briefly, the three simplest approaches are to:

- get the equivalent of a quasibinomial model by first fitting the model and adjusting the standard errors etc. *post hoc* (there's code on the GLMM FAQ to do this);
- fit a compound model (Beta-binomial) — although you'll have to switch to `glmmTMB` or some other package to do it
- add an observation-level random effect (technically, a "logit-Normal-binomial compound model")

As for the rescaling: hard to know without seeing your data, but guessing that your problem is *either* (1) you're treating `Year` as a numeric variable and haven't rescaled or centered it; or (2) you have [complete separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38493/how-to-deal-with-quasi-complete-separation-in-a-logistic-glmm).

---

Harrison, Xavier A. 2015. “A Comparison of Observation-Level Random Effect and Beta-Binomial Models for Modelling Overdispersion in Binomial Data in Ecology and Evolution.” PeerJ 3 (July): e1114. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.1114.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, very clear and helpful. I now understand and have worked around the problem.

Comment: OK: if this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept the answer ...