# Why does my logistic regression model fit probabilities numerically 0 or 1?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

When I fit a logistic regression model with my data set, I get the warning "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred", and the result for one of my dummy coefficients $x$ is nonsensical (extremely high estimate and variance). I'm aware that this warning usually indicates a perfect prediction problem, where the independent variable $x$ is perfectly separated by the dependent variable $y$. In my case, the reason seems to be that $y$ has the same value for all cases where $x=1$. However, in cases where $x=0$, the values of $y$ vary and it sometimes takes on the same value as when $x=0$. So $y$ doesn't perfectly separate $x$, but still this is what causes the problem. When I change just one of the $y$ values for $x=1$, the model estimation works fine.

Why does this error occur in my case, if the perfect prediction problem isn't the cause? I'm not looking for a solution, I just want to understand the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [How to deal with quasi-complete separation in a logistic GLMM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38493/how-to-deal-with-quasi-complete-separation-in-a-logistic-glmm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you will get this warning if *any* of the predictions are 1 or 0, rather than *all* of them.  This is because the contribution to the gradient of the loss function with respect to the parameters will be zero for that pattern as it is proportional to $y_i \times (1 - y_i)$ which will be zero for such points.

However, @Jarle_Tufto also is correct to point out that the logistic regression problem does not have a unique coefficient for this problem (see below - please forgive my ropey drawing)[image].  Say 2/3 of the examples for x=0 have y = 0 and 1/3 y = 1 and all of the points at x=1 have y=1, then any solution that will give those values at those points will have the same value for the loss function.  Adding a regularisation term to get it to choose the smallest slope resolves that indeterminancy (and probably generalise better)