# Mixed effects model for experimental setup

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, nested-models

I conducted an experiment with a system that allows to perform a task on a test-object using several methods. The quality of how the task was performed is measured by an error.

I measured the errors of 10 methods each conducted by 5 users on 2 test-objects whereas each user conducted 6 attempts per method and test-objects.

I would like to model this setup using a linear mixed effects model. In particular, I would like to evaluate whether there are (significant) differences

- between users (intrauser reliability)
- within users (interuser reliability)
- across test-objects (across test-object reliability)
- between methods

I think I have

- fixed effects: method
- random effects: user, test-object

Accordingly, the model would be

`error ~ methods + (1|user) + (1|test-object)`

Is that correct?

Furthermore, how can I know if I have a nested structure? Accordingly I would require a term like `(1|User/Attempt)`?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are only 2 levels of the `test-object` variable? If so then it is questionable to use `test-object` as a random effect - just retain it as a fixed effect

Comment: Yes that is correct, I can change it to a fixed effect. The question if I need a term like `(1|User/Attempt)` remains though?

Answer (score 2):

From your description, to fit a linear mixed effects model to your data you *could* use:

```
error ~ methods + (1|user) + (1|test-object)
```

Nesting is a property of the experimental design itself. From your description, a `test-object` does not *belong* to a particular `user`, and neither does a particular `user` belong to a particular `test-object` in the sense that a child would *belong* to, say, a class in a school, in a nested design. So you do not have nested data.

Therefore you do not need `(1|user/test-object)` - though it is worth noting that the results should be the same, provided that the variables are encoded appropriately. See the accepted answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified) for more details.

Finally, with only 2 levels of `test-object`, it doesn't really meet the [requirements](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-number-of-groups-for-a-random-effects-factor) for random effects, so a better model may be:

```
error ~ methods * test-object + (1|user)
```