# Stats questions for a laboratory experiment with a small number of animals

Tags: mixed-model, sample-size

I've been asked to run the stats on an animal behaviour experiment performed in a laboratory setting and, coming from a field ecology background, I have some basic questions regarding how I should proceed.

The experiments were testing the ability of *three* individual animals to retrieve a piece of food under two sets of conditions: whether the piece of food was alive or not (let's call it "state"), and whether the piece of food was suspended in the air or on the ground (let's call it "placement"). The response variable is the latency of each individual to successfully retrieve the food from the beginning of the trial. Latency is a continuous variable, whereas State and Placement are both categorical (with two categories each). The minimum number of trials for an individual per treatment is 8, the maximum is 36.

My basic models so far are thus: Latency ~ State + Placement + State*Placement + (1|Individual)

My questions are:

1. I understand that random effects shouldn't be used if there's fewer than 5 groups, however it "feels" wrong to simply pool everything together without some delineation of individuals. Should "Individual" be changed to a fixed effect? ([This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/157350) answer suggests that there may be little harm in having fewer than 5 levels, but I would like to double check)
2. Given that it's the same individuals being tested multiple times on the same paradigm, should I be accounting for repeated measures in the model, such as a "TrialNumber" effect?
   If so, would my model then become: Latency ~ State + Placement + State*Placement + (1|Individual) + (1|TrialNum)?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Suttree. You certainly shouldn't pool everything without delineation of individuals. Repeating an experiment lots of times with the same individual is called 'pseudoreplication'. Taking lots of measurements of each individual gives you a more accurate measurement for each individual, but it does not give you a bigger sample of the overall population. I would say any results from this are anecdotal at best, repeat for more individuals and then you can start to think about a statistical analysis. Have a read up on degrees of freedom.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. No chance for more animals/trials, unfortunately.

Comment: If you had sufficient replicates, then you might want to consider the effect of trial number, although possibly you'd need to consider an underlying time series regression in case there was a non-random effect of time (e.g. the animal got bored, or more practiced).

Comment: I think your basic model would be a reasonable place to start though, if you had enough replicates (but I don't think that you do).

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your input and advice!