# How to control for a variable (gender of participants) in GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, controlling-for-a-variable

I recently tested some participants on a navigation task. The success rate in the navigation task is a binomial record of pass (1) and fail (0). I assessed participants in different environmental blocks. I also administered a mental rotation test (MRT). My goal is to see the interaction effect of MRT and blocks on success rate. However,  sex/gender of the participants has a significant relationship with success rate. My question is how to control for this variable in my GLMM model. I have a possible model but I am not sure if it is correct.

Success rate data= binomial (1 or 0),
Block data = categorical(B1, B2, B3, B4),
MRT data = integer between 1 to 12,
Sex data = (1 or 0)

I normalized the data before applying the model.

note:I had a repeated measure design as each participant is tested in different blocks.

```r
model1 <- glmer(Success ~ Block * MRT + (1|sex) + (1|Subject),  
                data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Comment: I don't think you should have sex as a random effect. Because there are only two levels in your data, you should have it as a fixed effect if you want to control for it:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-number-of-groups-for-a-random-effects-factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not make sense for `sex` to be a grouping variable for random intecepts. It has only two levels and is in many scenarios it will be a confounding variable, or possible a competing exposure. In either case the best way to control for it, is by fitting fixed effects for it:

```
glmer(Success ~ Block * MRT + sex + (1|Subject),  
            data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! I corrected the model.